# ArrayList is adding only one element

Tags: java

In my `main` method:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          IMiniMap<String,Integer> map = new SimpleListMM<String,Integer>();
            map.put("B",15);
            map.put("A",5);
            map.put("R",-5);
            map.put("D",55);
            map.put("Poems",128);
            map.put("Plays",256);

            System.out.println(map.size());
            System.out.println(map.keys());

    }
}
```

when `map` calls `put` and adds elements in ArrayList, in my method it only adds one element. When I call `map.size` it returs me only `1` and when I call `map.keys` it returns only `"B"`. Here's the code:
class SimpleListMM

```
    public class SimpleListMM<K,V> extends AbstractListMM<K,V> {
    public SimpleListMM()
        {
            super(new ArrayList<K>(), new ArrayList<V>());
        }
    public V put(K key, V value)
        {
            if(keys.size() == 0)
            {
                keys.add(key);
                vals.add(value);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
            {
                if(keys.get(i).equals(key))
                    vals.set(i, value);
                /*else
                {
                    keys.add(key);
                    vals.add(value);
                }*/
            }
            return (V)vals;
        }
}
```

Class AbstractListMM

```
public abstract class AbstractListMM<K,V> implements IMiniMap<K,V>{

    protected List <K> keys; 
    protected List <V> vals;

// Initialize the lists of keys and values with a concrete instance
public AbstractListMM()
{
    this.keys = new ArrayList<K>();
    this.vals = new ArrayList<V>();
}
public AbstractListMM(List <K> keys, List <V> vals)
{
    this.keys = keys;
    this.vals = vals;
}

// Return the number of bindings based on the size of the key list
public int size()
{
    return keys.size();
}
public List<K> keys()
{
     List<K> newKeys = this.keys;
     return newKeys;
} 
public abstract V put(K key, V value);

}
}
```

Comment: Uncomment the else statement in your `put` method.

Comment: @ChristofferPasser, if I uncomment it, the result happens to be `32`

Comment: Ah.. That check shouldn't be in the `foor` loop.
I suggest you make a check before the for-loop. Checking whether the key is in the `keys` list. If it is - run the for-loop. Else add it.

Comment: @ChristofferPasser, what do you mean that check should not be inside the for-loop?

Comment: I have posted an answer to show what I mean :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding only once an element in keys ArrayList, at the beginning when it is empty.
Something like this should work:
.....

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    if(keys.get(i).equals(key)) {
        vals.set(i, value);
        found = true;
        break;        
    }
if (!found) {
    keys.add(key);
    vals.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method for put, I see two things that jump out to me as weird. Firstly, you have an if statement around your insertion, "if(keys.size() ==0)" which is why only the first call of the method is actually adding something to the list. On the second call, the list size is no longer 0 and nothing gets added.

In the return for the put method, you're also casting the entire list as a single object of type V, but in reality it's a List. I'm not sure why your method is returning anything at all to be honest, but maybe there's some weird java thing or concept about your code that I'm not getting.

Either way, if you remove or alter that if condition it should fix the problem you are having as I understand it. Perhaps you meant to add an else clause after it?

```
if(keys.size() == 0)
{
    keys.add(key);
    vals.add(value);
}
for(...)
```

becomes:

```
if(keys.size() == 0)
{
    keys.add(key);
    vals.add(value);
}
else
{
    for(...)
```

I think that's more in line with what you intended :)

Comment: What happens when you try it? It still only adds the one item?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are two options.
1. The key exists in the list. Find the key and update the value.
2. The key does not exists in the list and must be added to it.

```
if(keys.contains(key)) {
    vals.set(keys.indexOf(key), value);
} else {
   keys.add(key);
   values.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [cbhedd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3677605/cbhedd) said, the function put is never setting any value after first put because of the size check.

But when you add "A" to the map, the for loop checks only for duplicate key and no where your vals will be set. The check for keys.size() == 0 may not be necessary because the value never gets added even with else loop.

In order to avoid duplicate keys one method would be

```
if(keys != null)
{
    if(keys.contains(key))
    {
       vals.set(keys.indexOf(key), value);
    }
    else
    {
       keys.add(key);
       vals.add(value);
    }
}
else
{
    keys = new ArrayList<K>();
       keys.add(key);
       vals.add(value);
}
```